# rails has_many through same destination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I have a User, Post and Like model. A user has many posts, and a user can like posts.

```
  has_many :user_posts
  has_many :users, through: :user_posts
  has_many :likes
  has_many :users, through: :likes
```

On the other side my rspecs are:

```
  it { should have_many(:users).through(:user_posts) }
  it { should have_many(:user_posts) }
  it { should have_many(:likes) }
  it { should have_many(:user_likes).through(:likes) }
```

This doesn't seem to go down very well, as rspec complains there already is a relationship through user:

```
 Expected Post to have a has_many association called users (, Expected users to have users through likes, but got it through user_posts)
```

I tried all sort of combinations with class_name without much success. How should I define these relationships?

Comment: Shouldn't a User just has_many :posts. Why user_posts?

Comment: Your question/example code isn't very clear - are all those relations on the same model?  What models do each of your RSpec expecations relate to? One of your expectations mentions :user_likes but thats not in your initially stated relations.

Comment: @LannyBose, you're right. Initially I thought I could do with one relation between user and posts: a user has posts and a post is liked by a user. But that obviously won't work hence why I'm looking at the liked model. That does mean indeed that I can remove the many to many relations in favor of a has_many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making some inferences based on the code above. Let me explain the choices I made...

Your terminology around "user posts" is ambiguous to me, because it's unclear if a "user post" is something a user **liked** or something a user **authored**.

In my code, `has_many :posts` is referring to *authorship* and does not demand a join table because a post only has one author. On the other hand, `has_many :liked_posts` needs to go `through:` a join table (Likes) since it's a many-to-many relationship.

The only other thing that I've done differently is the use of the `source:` option in the association. Since a Like has no idea what either `liked_posts` or `users_who_liked` are, you need to tell it which of it's *own* associations to follow to get the records.

You can read more about Associations in the [Rails API Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many).

```
class User < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :likes
  has_many :liked_posts, through: :likes, source: :post
end

class Like < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to: post
end

class Post < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_many :likes
  has_many :users_who_liked, through: likes, source: :user
end
```

Finally, as feedback on your question as-written: Tom's right in his comment above. It's not clear which classes those associations are a part of. Does a User have Users twice? Confusing. If I mis-inferred any of your business rules, let me know and I can revise my thoughts.